# How to iterate in a grib?

Tags: python, python-xarray, grib

I am trying to iterate over a grib file to get all the data but I don't know how to do it. I am doing it in Python.

I am using this code

```
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset("myFile.grib2", engine="pynio")

for v in ds:
    print(ds[v])
```

The result i am getting are some outputs like this:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'PERPW_P0_L1_GLL0' (lat_0: 336, lon_0: 720)>
[241920 values with dtype=float32]
Coordinates:
  * lat_0    (lat_0) float32 90.0 89.5 89.0 88.5 ... -76.0 -76.5 -77.0 -77.5
  * lon_0    (lon_0) float32 0.0 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 ... 358.0 358.5 359.0 359.5
Attributes:
    center:                                         US National Weather Servi...
    production_status:                              Operational products
    long_name:                                      Primary wave mean period
    units:                                          s
    grid_type:                                      Latitude/longitude
    parameter_discipline_and_category:              Oceanographic products, W...
    parameter_template_discipline_category_number:  [ 0 10  0 11]
    level_type:                                     Ground or water surface
    level:                                          [1.]
    forecast_time:                                  [219]
    forecast_time_units:                            hours
    initial_time:                                   01/18/2021 (00:00)
```

I am using this [file](ftp://ftpprd.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gens/prod/gefs.20210222/00/wave/gridded/gefs.wave.t00z.c00.global.0p25.f000.grib2) from NOAA.

As far as I know this are like the columns of a table. How can I get the data, for instance, of all *level* values?

Comment: Could you please post the code you are currently using? Are you using a specific library?

Comment: @nehalem i have edited the question with the code

Comment: Can you specify what is your goal? "get all the data" is a bit generic, `ds` is technically "all the data"...what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MatteoDeFelice I want to get all values of level field. I understand grib file as this [photo](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/awl_zVoOIXrLY5e0XAucZvQwqXi4a2X2hbp7eQXJHK41qFW-_DUjlqN9lzPwSRE8UTA5o7LgvgoBFGyNfqPkjYkybgfWRCaWBu0d1aQuVz4B6yvnAQ). I have updated the question to show what I get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use pygrib for GRIB file, but xarray also good I think.

```
G = pygrib.open('file.grb'):
for g in G:
    print(g)
```

Get coords and values like this for example...

```
latlons = g.latlons()
values = g.values
```

check out all the other data available with keys..
need to pick out valid times and forecast step offset, depending on the data.

`print(g.keys())`

Comment: Thanks for it. I think was missing the way to get all the available keys.

Comment: how to pull values at each forecast time?

Answer (score 2):

`xarray` provides an interface to the gridded data (as you can see [in the documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/data-structures.html)).

I use the package `cfgrib` to access GRIB data. It's solid and developed by ECMWF (https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib).

So, if you do:

```py
import xarray as xr

d = xr.open_dataset('gefs.wave.t00z.c00.global.0p25.f000.grib2', engine = 'cfgrib')
print(d)
```

You get this:

```py
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (latitude: 721, level: 3, longitude: 1440)
Coordinates:
    time        datetime64[ns] 2020-12-01
    step        timedelta64[ns] 00:00:00
    surface     int32 1
  * latitude    (latitude) float64 90.0 89.75 89.5 89.25 ... -89.5 -89.75 -90.0
  * longitude   (longitude) float64 0.0 0.25 0.5 0.75 ... 359.3 359.5 359.8
    valid_time  datetime64[ns] 2020-12-01
  * level       (level) int32 1 2 3
Data variables:
    ws          (latitude, longitude) float32 nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan
    wdir        (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    u           (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    v           (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    siconc      (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    swh         (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    paramId_0   (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    mwp         (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    perpw       (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    mwd         (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    dirpw       (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    shww        (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    swell       (level, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    mpww        (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    swper       (level, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    wvdir       (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    swdir       (level, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
Attributes:
    GRIB_edition:            2
    GRIB_centre:             kwbc
    GRIB_centreDescription:  US National Weather Service - NCEP 
    GRIB_subCentre:          0
    Conventions:             CF-1.7
    institution:             US National Weather Service - NCEP 
    history:                 2021-02-23T16:14:32 GRIB to CDM+CF via cfgrib-0....
```

Each data variable has its own coordinates and you can access it through `xarray`:

```py
print(d['swh'])
<xarray.DataArray 'swh' (latitude: 721, longitude: 1440)>
array([[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       ...,
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
    time        datetime64[ns] 2020-12-01
    step        timedelta64[ns] 00:00:00
    surface     int32 1
  * latitude    (latitude) float64 90.0 89.75 89.5 89.25 ... -89.5 -89.75 -90.0
  * longitude   (longitude) float64 0.0 0.25 0.5 0.75 ... 359.3 359.5 359.8
    valid_time  datetime64[ns] 2020-12-01
Attributes:
    GRIB_paramId:                             140229
    GRIB_shortName:                           swh
    GRIB_units:                               m
    GRIB_name:                                Significant height of combined ...
    GRIB_cfVarName:                           swh
    GRIB_dataType:                            an
    GRIB_missingValue:                        9999
    GRIB_numberOfPoints:                      1038240
    GRIB_typeOfLevel:                         surface
    GRIB_NV:                                  0
    GRIB_stepUnits:                           1
    GRIB_stepType:                            instant
    GRIB_gridType:                            regular_ll
    GRIB_gridDefinitionDescription:           Latitude/longitude. Also called...
    GRIB_Nx:                                  1440
    GRIB_iDirectionIncrementInDegrees:        0.25
    GRIB_iScansNegatively:                    0
    GRIB_longitudeOfFirstGridPointInDegrees:  0.0
    GRIB_longitudeOfLastGridPointInDegrees:   359.750016
    GRIB_Ny:                                  721
    GRIB_jDirectionIncrementInDegrees:        0.25
    GRIB_jPointsAreConsecutive:               0
    GRIB_jScansPositively:                    0
    GRIB_latitudeOfFirstGridPointInDegrees:   90.0
    GRIB_latitudeOfLastGridPointInDegrees:    -90.0
    long_name:                                Significant height of combined ...
    units:                                    m
```

The variables are `DataArray` but you can access the underlying gridded data using `values`, so:

```py
d['swh'].values
array([[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       ...,
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]], dtype=float32)
```

or using the `to_*` functions to export, for example to a Pandas DataFrame:

```py
print(d['swh'].to_dataframe().head())
                         time   step  surface valid_time  swh
latitude longitude                                           
90.0     0.00      2020-12-01 0 days        1 2020-12-01  NaN
         0.25      2020-12-01 0 days        1 2020-12-01  NaN
         0.50      2020-12-01 0 days        1 2020-12-01  NaN
         0.75      2020-12-01 0 days        1 2020-12-01  NaN
         1.00      2020-12-01 0 days        1 2020-12-01  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by *level* values, but for the file you linked, all of the variables are 2-dimensional fields as a function of time. They aren't really like columns of a table, but are time series of 2D grids.